# Not able to modify global variables inside function

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, web-deployment

I am trying to **modify variables declared outside any function scope**, within the function, however the variables **remain undefined**. I am triggering the function using **window.onload**.

Here is the JS code:

```
var lat;
var long;

function showPosition(position) {
  lat = position.coords.latitude;
  long = position.coords.longitude;

  const apikey_gmaps = "xyz";


  fetch("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+lat+","+long+"&key="+apikey_gmaps)
  .then(
    function(response){
      if (response.status !== 200){
        console.log("Error while getting location");
        return;
      }

      response.json().then(function(address){
        var parsedAddress = address.results[0].formatted_address;
        var city = address.results[0].address_components[0].long_name;
      });
    }
  )
    .catch(function(err){
      console.log(err);
    });
}

function error(err) {
    console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
  }

//Function to get location
function getLocation() {
  var weatherText = document.querySelector("#xyz");
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,error,options);
  } else {
    weatherText.innerHTML = "Error getting location";
  }
  function ErrorCase(error) {
    weatherText.innerHTML = "Couldn't fetch location";
  }
}


window.onload = function(){
     getLocation();
     console.log(lat,long);
     }
```

This logs **undefined undefined** in the console. However, if I call the functions in my Chrome dev console directly (without onload), it works pretty fine.

I have tried using body onload="someFn()", tried declaring the variables inside onload=function(){}, without any success.

How can I modify these global variables?

Comment: Where & how you’re calling that function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,error,options);
```

[Geolocation.getCurrentPosition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition) - this API takes first parameter as **success** callback and second optional parameter as **error** callback.

It **asynchronously** attempts to obtain the current location of the device. If the attempt is successful, success callback will be invoked.

Since *console.log* is below getLocation() function. At the time of execution, the asynchronous request may not be completed and success callback not invoked.

So value for **lat** and **long** are not filled at that time and **undefined** is returned.

To wait until the callback function is completed, you can use a flag variable along with setInterval.

```
<script>
var lat;
var long;
var callBackStatus;
function showPosition(position) {
    callBackStatus = true;
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    long = position.coords.longitude;

    const apikey_gmaps = "xyz";


    fetch("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+lat+","+long+"&key="+apikey_gmaps)
        .then(
            function(response){
                if (response.status !== 200){
                    console.log("Error while getting location");
                    return;
                }

                response.json().then(function(address){
                    var parsedAddress = address.results[0].formatted_address;
                    var city = address.results[0].address_components[0].long_name;
                });
            }
        )
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });
}

function error(err) {
    callBackStatus = true;
    console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
}

//Function to get location
function getLocation() {
    var weatherText = document.querySelector("#xyz");
    callBackStatus = false;
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,error);
    } else {
        weatherText.innerHTML = "Error getting location";
    }
    function ErrorCase(error) {
        weatherText.innerHTML = "Couldn't fetch location";
    }
}


window.onload = function(){
        getLocation();
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            if (callBackStatus) {
                console.log(lat, long);
                clearInterval(interval);
            } else {
                console.log("Waiting for callback");
            }
        }, 50);
    }
    </script>
```